# Query dynamoDB based on HASH key only efficiently and cost effectively

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a dynamoDB table with a HASH key and a SORT key.

**Now I have a situation where I need to get table contents based on the HASH key only and it will return an array of items. **

I am able to do this with .query() operation

```
    const params = {
      KeyConditionExpression: `${key} = :${key}`,
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        [`:${key}`]: value,
      },
      TableName: tableName,
    }
    const result = await this.dynamodb.query(params).promise()
```

Now the question I have is around 'best practices' and 'cost'.

GOAL: I need to get many items based on one key.

QUESTION: **Is this the best way to do it**? Or am I performing a full scan every time I query?

NOTE: I have knowledge on GSI/LSI but since I'm querying on the HASH key only, I think making another Index is redundant?

```
    const params = {
      KeyConditionExpression: `${key} = :${key}`,
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        [`:${key}`]: value,
      },
      TableName: tableName,
    }
    const result = await this.dynamodb.query(params).promise()
```

Comment: If you perform a query you perform a query. If you perform a scan then you perform a scan. They are different APIs. A query cannot scan the entire db (unless your entire DB has the same hash key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Query is an efficient operation. It does not do a full table scan, it only reads the items related to the provided hash key.

If you want it to be more efficient you can provide a condition on the sort key to help filter the result set, such as `SK begins_with(ABC)`.

And you are correct that an index is not required, as you are already as efficient as you can be.